# What is the difference between `removeQuery()` and `clearParameters()` in org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder of HttpClient 4.3.1?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

It seems to me that these two methods ([`URIBuilder.removeQuery`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#removeQuery%28%29) and [`URIBuilder.clearParameters`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#clearParameters%28%29)) do exactly the same thing, so I am not sure why there are two choices. In what circumstances should I use one over the other?

I noticed that the corresponding [`URIBuilder.setQuery`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#setQuery%28java.lang.String%29) method is marked as deprecated in favor of [`URIBuilder.setParameters`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#setParameters%28java.util.List%29), but [`URIBuilder.removeQuery`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#removeQuery%28%29) is not. Am I mistaken in thinking that perhaps it should be?

**UPDATE:** 
Oleg offered the following explanation on the [dev mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=httpclient-commons-dev&m=138321351623361&w=2):

> The reason for deprecation of the #setQuery method was its inconsistency
>   of its contract with all other methods of the class. #setQuery expected
>   input to be URL encoded whereas all other methods expect unescaped
>   input. The choice was between changing the contract of the method and by
>   doing so breaking pretty much every single application reliant on
>   URIBuilder or method deprecation in favor of another method with
>   slightly less intuitive name. So, one should be using [set|clear|
>   add]Parameter[s] methods to work with query parameters and the #setCustomQueury
>   method to set custom queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, exact difference is very small, if you look into the source :

```
public URIBuilder removeQuery() {
    this.queryParams = null;
    this.query = null; // <- this is the only difference
    this.encodedQuery = null;
    this.encodedSchemeSpecificPart = null;
    return this;
}
```

vs

```
public URIBuilder clearParameters() {
    this.queryParams = null;
    this.encodedQuery = null;
    this.encodedSchemeSpecificPart = null;
    return this;
}
```

So, `clearParameters` will keep your query object.

Comment: Weird. Any idea why one would want to not clear `query` when clearing the `queryParams`? (Not to mention why the `removeQuery` method wouldn't be implemented by a call to `clearParamters` followed by setting `query` to null.) The API provides these two ways of manipulating the query string but makes them mutually exclusive, so I thought that using either way would invalidate the other data.

Comment: Yes, `query` and `queryParams` are mutually exclusive, meaning you "nullify" your `query` next time you `setParameters` after `clearParameters`. Indeed, they could've set `query` to `null` in `clearParameters` too. As for the second "why" : my guess is they decided just to slightly touch `removeQuery` (was there before 4.3), while introducing new `clearParameters` API in 4.3.